# Partioning sd not detecting

Tags: external-sd, link2sd

I have partitioned my sd using mini-Partion tool.My sd partion shows unallocted and file system as logiclly and i know that for link2sd it should be primary.how to convert to primary file system.i dint find any option for that in mini-Partion.

Comment: Do you have windows pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have windows pc try this. Back up any data in sd card and save it in pc.

1. Insert your sd card in any card reader and insert in pc
2. Press `Windows Key + R` and the Run dialog should popup. Type in
   `diskpart` and hit Enter.
3. Once DiskPart comes up, type `list disk`. (This will show you all the
   disks that are attached to the system. You'll want to note the
   number of the one that is your sd card/flash drive. You should be
   able to distinguish it based on it's small size compared to your
   hard disks.)
4. select the sd card by typing `select disk number` (eg:`select disk 2`)
5. Type list part and it will show you what partitions are already on
   the disk.
6. Next to remove all the partitions from the disk just type `clean`.
   Afterwards type list part and the console should say that there are
   now no partitions on the disk.
7. (If you need more than one partition goto step 8 )Type `create partition primary` and this will create a new partition that fills the available space on the disk. You can type list part to confirm that the new partition has been created.Goto step 11
8. If you want it a particular size add the size parameter `size=20` eg: `create partition primary size=100` (with the size in MBs)
9. select the new partition `select partition 1` (you can list partition using `list partition` command)
10. Now format it to fat32 `format FS=Fat32 label="SDCARD"` repeat 8,9,10 to create more partition (you can use exFat instead of Fat32 if you have more than 4gb sdcard, you can omit the label part if not needed)
11. Thats it now you can close diskpart and eject the sd card and insert in your
    android

Comment: Thank a lot...But when i tried to open the drive.it asked for format; so i formatted..so i lost the data's.